# Include a 'time' variable in an interrupted time series regression analysis?

Tags: regression, time-series, t-test, ancova

I have a time series where a specific event occurs. I want to see if there is a significant difference in the mean pre- and post- event. The time series is first adjusted for seasonality, and then run as follows:

```
Adjusted Values = B0 + B1*Pre/PostFlag + B2*OtherFactors
```

I am arguing that you MUST have another regressor that accounts for the fact that the observations in the regression are still a series - that is, there is order to them, even though trend and seasonality is removed. Otherwise it doesn't account for the fact that this is a time series, and our observations are in a particular order. Like this:

```
Adjusted Values = B0 + B1*Time + B2*Pre/PostFlag + B3*OtherFactors
```

How do I convince my friend that the latter is correct?

Comment: It isn't at all clear that you are correct, for two reasons.  The first is that the nature of the series might be that after the adjustments, there is no more temporal structure left--time adds no more information.  The second is that there are many methods to account for the temporal structure of time series in addition to using lagged regressors; the most prominent is to model the serial correlation.  Thus, if you want to make any progress, you will need to identify some relevant characteristics *in your specific data* that indicate additional regressors are needed.